# I am working on react native project using EXPO.IO, today it gives error Unable to resolve module @babel

Tags: react-native, expo

The error is like this Unable to resolve module 'module://@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireWildcard.js' 
Even I have added @babel/runtime but still giving me this error.

This is what I've added in babel.config.js

```
const babelRuntime = [
  require('@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'),
  require ('babel-preset-expo'),
  require ( '@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55"'),
  {
    helpers: true,
    regenerator: true,
  },
];
```

Comment: Did you create new project with expo init myproject

Comment: No, its old one and I am using expo.io

Comment: What is old?  Your project?